# Entity Framework connections strings messing up app.config

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework inside a DLL.

VS creates a app.config, but when I run the application I receive this exception.

"The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."

Comment: Please give us some code - my crystal ball is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include that connection string in the start up project of your solution. If it is a Asp.Net WebForms/MVC application include that connection string in the `Web.Config` file or if it is a Windows or Console App include it in `App.Config` file.